# microSD card jumps to read-only on one specific computer when using one specific program

Tags: sd-card, micro-sd-card, steam-os, steam-deck

I'm just gonna explain this situation, and I'd love to know what's going on, how to fix it, and ideally I hope this brand new microSD card isn't dead or something.

If I:

1. plug it into my Linux desktop using ANY card reader (I've tried multiple and plugged them into separate USB headers), and
2. use steamtinkerlaunch to run an instance of ModOrganizer 2 on it (long story)

Then without fail, the card kicks into read-only until I eject it and plug it back in. This only happens when I run ModOrganizer 2.

However, my main usage of this card is on my Steam Deck, and it works perfectly fine there. Even when I run ModOrganizer 2 through steamtinkerlaunch like on the other computer and modify all those same files, but also do anything on it in general, such as transfer or play games. It never kicks into read-only mode.

And earlier today, I was using the card extensively on the desktop with no issues. Only tonight is this specific chain of events suddenly, reliably triggering read-only, only on this one computer, regardless of multiple varieties of card readers.

What gives? *Is* this card dying??

Comment: Is the _card itself_ or the _filesystem_ switching to read-only?

Comment: How certain are you that on the "good" computer that the card isn't still read-only? If you write a new file to it, safely eject the card, and the reinsert it is the file still there? Some systems may be caching the contents and just *look* like it is working until you try to use it elsewhere.

Comment: @Mokubai It's definitely working on the new computer. I've written new files, ejected, and reinserted to find the files there several times, on both computers in fact (even the one that's having trouble with this one program). On the good computer specifically, I've written hundreds of GB of data and am continuing to now.

Comment: @user1686 I don't know. How would I check? The filesystem on the card is definitely switching to read-only, and beyond that I have no idea. It's back on read/write once I eject and reinsert.

Comment: To start with, what tells you that it's read-only, and how does it tell you that?

Comment: @user1686 It's marked by the system as a "read-only filesystem" wherever relevant. But not until it's triggered by the one progam on the one computer.

Comment: Does `dmesg` have any kernel messages from the time when this happens?

Comment: dmesg message is: [51701.517303] EXT4-fs error (device sdf1): ext4_lookup:1838: inode #54788104: comm pool-Thunar: deleted inode referenced: 57805330. This prompted me to run fsck, which fixed a ton of errors. Then I remounted and it seems to be working fine. So I guess it's fixed? I wonder if this is a consequence of just removing the microSD from the Deck while it's asleep, rather than after a shutdown or eject.

Answer (score 1):

dmesg message is: `[51701.517303] EXT4-fs error (device sdf1): ext4_lookup:1838: inode #54788104: comm pool-Thunar: deleted inode referenced: 57805330`

This prompted me to run fsck, which fixed a ton of errors. Then I remounted and it seems to be working fine. So I guess it's fixed? I wonder if this is a consequence of just removing the microSD from the Deck while it's asleep, rather than after a shutdown or eject.

Comment: Okay, now please accept your own answer so it's marked resolved.